# EF Core ToList DBNull to int?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

The EF core Firebird provider does not convert DBNull to nullable types. When I have an entity with a nullable `int?` property and I simply get all entries in a table using `await this._dbContext.EmpLevels.ToListAsync()` I get the exception that I cannot cast a DBNull to Int32 as stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.system-iconvertible-toint32?view=net-6.0. Theoretically, this makes sense because an `int` cannot represent `null` but it's a nullable property.

I found a lot of questions with the same problem, but not related to Firebird, where they have access to the readers or data tables, but in my case, I don't have them. So how can I parse null values from firebird into a nullable `int?`

**EDIT:**

But when I add `HasConversion` it works fine although I just pass the type of the property:

**Before:** `entity.Property(e => e.CertId).HasColumnName("CERT_ID");`
**After:** `entity.Property(e => e.CertId).HasColumnName("CERT_ID").HasConversion<int?>();`

The problem is that I don't have to add it to the property `CertId`. I first added `HasConversion` to the wrong property by accident and this worked too (property: `CapId`) although it's not even a nullable int because `CertId` is the only nullable.

**EDIT 2:**

Entity:

```
public partial class EmpLevel
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; } = default!;
    public int CapId { get; set; } = default!;
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } = default!;
    public int LevelId { get; set; } = default!;
    public int? CertId { get; set; }

    public virtual Certificate? Cert { get; set; }
    public virtual EmpsCap EmpsCap { get; set; } = default!;
    public virtual CapLevel Level { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class CapsDbContext : DbContext {
    ...
    public virtual DbSet<EmpLevel> EmpLevels { get; set; }
    ...

    public CapsDbContext(DbContextOptions<CapsDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        ...

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmpLevel>(entity => {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.EmpId, e.CapId, e.StartDate });

            entity.ToTable("EMP_LEVELS");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.CertId);

            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.CapId, e.EmpId });

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.LevelId);

            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.StartDate, e.CapId, e.EmpId });

            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.StartDate, e.CapId, e.EmpId })
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.EmpId).HasColumnName("EMP_ID");

            entity.Property(e => e.CapId).HasColumnName("CAP_ID");

            entity.Property(e => e.StartDate)
                .HasColumnType("DATE")
                .HasColumnName("START_DATE");

            entity.Property(e => e.CertId).HasColumnName("CERT_ID").HasConversion<int?>();

            entity.Property(e => e.LevelId).HasColumnName("LEVEL_ID");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Cert)
                .WithMany(p => p.EmpLevels)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CertId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_CERT_EMPLEVEL");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Level)
                .WithMany(p => p.EmpLevels)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.LevelId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_LEVEL_EMPLEVEL");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.EmpsCap)
                .WithMany(p => p.EmpLevels)
                .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.EmpId, d.CapId })
                .HasConstraintName("FK_EMPSCAPS_EMPLEVEL");
        });

        ...
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
    at System.DBNull.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
    at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value, IFormatProvider provider)
    at FirebirdSql.Data.Common.DbValue.GetInt32()
    at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 I)
    at lambda_method1001(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
    at System.DBNull.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
    at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value, IFormatProvider provider)
    at FirebirdSql.Data.Common.DbValue.GetInt32()
    at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 I)
    at lambda_method1001(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
```

Comment: *but not related to Firebird, where they have access to the readers or data tables, but in my case, I don't have them* --- what's so special with Firebird?

Comment: Could you please provide the text of the exception (so that we can see the name of the column), your class representing the table in DB and how it's configured if FluentAPI is used?

Comment: Post the *actual* query and configuration code and *actual* full exception text. I seriously doubt that FIrebird can't handle nulls.

Comment: Do you use this provider https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/NETProvider ? If so, there is an open issue in their github, very similar to yours https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/NETProvider/issues/840. It was opened a long time ago and seems like no work done on it.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo See **Edit 2**. I also found this issue on GitHub, but as you already mentioned no comments, no one seems to work on it and it looks like the issue was created by a bot.

Comment: So anything in response to the edit?